# How can i make a function which will print the values of the list through 2 specific steps(Python)

Tags: python, list, function, arguments, yield

I have a function, which will take 3 arguments: list, step1 and step2. I need to write a generator-function, which will print 1 value step by step at each iteration. Here is an example

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]  # ordinary list
b = generate_step(a, 1, 2)  # this is the function with this list and two steps.

next(b)  # I need to print all the iterations
next(b)
next(b)
next(b)
```

output will be

```
1 
3
4
6  # I mean the steps alternate
7
```

I hope I could explain. So, now this is my code

```
def generate_step(lst, step1, step2):
    l1 = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(lst):
        for_step1 = lst[::step1]
        l1.append(for_step1)
        i += 1
        for_step2 = lst[::step2]
        l1.append(for_step2)
        i += 1
        for j in range(0, len(l1)):
            yield l1[j]


a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
b = generate_step(a, 2, 3)
while True:
    try:
        print(next(b))
    except StopIteration:
        pass
        break
```

output is

```
[1, 3, 5, 7]
[1, 4, 7]
[1, 3, 5, 7]
[1, 4, 7]
[1, 3, 5, 7]
[1, 4, 7]
[1, 3, 5, 7]
[1, 4, 7]
[1, 3, 5, 7]
[1, 4, 7]
[1, 3, 5, 7]
[1, 4, 7]
[1, 3, 5, 7]
[1, 4, 7]
[1, 3, 5, 7]
[1, 4, 7]
[1, 3, 5, 7]
[1, 4, 7]
[1, 3, 5, 7]
[1, 4, 7]
```

which is not what the task asks... please help me to solve this problem. I have no idea how to make the steps alternate and how to display not a whole list but one number, according to the condition.

Comment: I'd expect the desired output to begin with a 1, not a 2. Could you explain why the 1 is skipped?

Comment: maybe it's a typo, I'll edit it now.

Comment: So you always yield the first item, *then* start skipping according to the two given steps?

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: A step of 1 seems to mean to advance by 1, not to skip one.

Comment: But the example still doesn't quite add up – it should be 1, 3, 4, 6, 7 if my interpretation is correct.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I just understand the task so. If you can help me with your example, I'll be grateful. I think you are right. I edited again...sorry for that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach based on `itertools`:

```
from itertools import chain, cycle, compress 
def generate_step(a, *steps): 
    selections = chain.from_iterable(
        [0] * (step - 1) + [1] for step in cycle(steps)
    ) 
    return compress(a, selections)
```

Example:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> list(generate_step(a, 1, 2))
[1, 3, 4, 6, 7]
```

The code first creates an iterable of "selections" that yields a zero for each element that should be skipped, and a 1 for each element that should be selected. These selections are then passed to [`itertools.compress()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) – one of the less frequently used functions in that library.

The function supports an arbitrary number of steps and cycles through them.

If you want to write the function from scratch, without using `itertools`, one possible approach is this:

```
def generate_step(a, *steps):
    a = iter(a)
    while True:
        for step in steps:
            for dummy in range(step):
                try:
                    x = next(a)
                except StopIteration:
                    return
            yield x
```

Comment: I got it, thanks, but do have an idea how to do it without ```import```?

Comment: Sure, but why? This is part of Python's standard library, and in CPython the module is even built into the interpreter itself, so importing doesn't load anything new into memory.

Comment: I just wonder how it can be solved without importing. And how can I do it with ```yield``` instead of ```return```

Comment: It's not built into the interpreter; it's loaded like any other module, but only a broken installation would be unable to load it. (And it does appear to be *preloaded*, if that's what you mean.)

Comment: @chepner The documentation states [it is compiled into the interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.builtin_module_names), and at least at some point in the past this was actually the case. I haven't checked the Python source code in ages, so I'm not sure the docs are still accurate, but unless you have evidence to the contrary I'll assume it is. :)